# Window snaps to bottom edge and cannot move vertically

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

When moving a window off the desktop horizontally, the window will push itself back onto the desktop.

However, when moving it to the bottom, it will do the same and snap to the bottom edge. The problem is that it will not unsnap. Min/maximizing the window does not fix the issue. Nothing short of closing/reopening seems to fix the problem.

Is there a way to fix or change this behavior? I can't seem to remember having this issue on my other systems...

System: Compaq Presario CQ56

Answer (score 0):

Haven's seen this problem mentioned anywhere else, but I did find the solution for myself.

For me, this problem (and a fullscreen issue) were fixed after fully updating. Never underestimate the power of updates!